# aligning list-style-image proportionally with text

Tags: html, list, css

So I have

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
li {
    list-style-image: url(../img/bullet.png); /* 13x13 px */
    /* line-height: 13px; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

which looks like

[image]

as you can see text and image element of `<li>` are not aligned vertically (image is higher than text), I tried applying line-height and vertical-align to it (commented out code), but it didn't even it out. Is there a way to achieve good alignment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The padding will affect only whatever is inside the element—the text, in your case.

The only position adjustment property available is [list-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position), but the only permitted values are `inherit`, `inside` or `outside`. The most common practice is to use:

```
list-style: none;
```

and then apply the desired image as the `<li>`'s background

```
li {
    /** the image will be vertically aligned in the center **/
    background: url(../img/bullet.png) left center no-repeat; 

    /** move the text to the right **/
    padding-left: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add no-repeat to your background property.

Comment: Using this method has some advantages.
You can adjust position really well.
When the `<li>` text wraps (think mobile phones), the text vertically aligns with the beginning of the first line.
You might need to add `min-height` if the bullet img is bigger than a line of text.

Answer (score 3):

you can have

```
<li><span style="top:-5px; position:relative;">Text shifted 5px upper</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

May define a img-tag or a background: url(..) for the li-tag instead of the "list-style-image"

Comment: Yea, but I kinda want to figure it out with list-style-image.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<p>You can have</p>
<ul>
  <li> <span>Hello</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```css
li {
   list-style-image: url('dot.png');
}
li > span {
   top:-3px; position:relative; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only have one line per list item you can add some `padding-bottom` to the `li` element

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add "no-repeat" to the background property