# Image not aligning with the text on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Image is not aligned with the text on GitHub Pages but it looks fine on GitHub repository.

As you can see below, images are aligned with the bulletpoint and text

[image: Image on Repository]

When I made a website using GitHub Pages' Dinky theme, images are not aligned anymore.

[image: Image on GitHub Pages]

How can I fix this problem?

Is there any way I can fix this problem without changing GitHub Pages theme, or using Gem?

I thought using html to upload images would work, but images won't show on the website.

This is the link to my [Repository](https://github.com/dounykim/MDcheck4/blob/master/networkx.md). It's written in Korean but images are in line 1867-1868

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, according the the [GFM specs (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#images) is that an image link `![foo](/url "title")` syntax generates an image link inside a *paragraph*.

```html
<p><img src="/url" alt="foo" title="title" /></p>
```

[Using html](https://gist.github.com/ChrisTollefson/a3af6d902a74a0afd1c2d79aadc9bb3f#image-links) might be a better option:

```html
text... <img alt="Image alt text" title="Optional image title"
     src="https://username.github.io/repo-name/img/pic.jpg "
/> ... text
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when adding an image inside the bullet point, the image is still off and not aligned with the text in bullet point. So I added ```align="center"``` like this  ```<img alt=”Image alt text” title=”Optional image title” src=”https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dounykim/MDcheck4/master/img/ec-2_.png align=”center” />``` . Then, it is not recognized as image anymore.

Comment: @DoHunKim " Then, it is not recognized as image anymore":  That is because you forgot the closing quotes after the filename: `src="https://raw...._.png" align="center" />`: note the `"` after `.png`, missing in your case.

Comment: Oh right. I just figured that out. But neither ```align="center"``` nor ```align="bottom"``` aligns the image with text inside the bullet point.

Comment: Is it impossible to align image with text inside the bullet point? Everything works fine when not using a bullet point

Comment: @DoHunKim I suspect the default stype associated with li is problematic here. Try and add a style as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28629341/6309.

Comment: @DoHunKim Or use your image as background for the list items: http://jsfiddle.net/gc9LC/

Comment: @DoHunKim Another technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BA2Lc/